# What all use cases we can automate in localization testing_selenium

Tags: automated-testing, selenium

We have a PHP web application, with base language English and native support for Japanese & Chinese.

1. We want to automate some part of it's localization testing, such as
   Link text, button text validation. (This seems doable with selenium).     However, how we should verify the texts with big paragraphs e.g. FAQs?
2. Also, we have a team in Japan which provides translation on PHP page
   itself.( Ideal would be to send it in key-value pair). How should I transform such files so that I can easily refer in code?
3. What would be the set of use cases that we can think of automating?

Comment: Is localization testing only about translations? Why do you want to automate it? Did you calculated ROI of that, i.e., costs of creating and maintaining tests for verification of translations?

Comment: I am already doing automation for its normal functionality. My higher authority wants it kind of POC, to show / see we can do it further for localization as well.

Comment: So to answer your question, actually no, as I am completely new to say anything on automated localization testing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can automate localised , get the data for the labels and link text of localised content in some file or excel sheet, you can convert it into UTF-8 or Shift-JIS  and getText, or Value of that particular webelement

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it is bit late. :) I managed to work upon it as per the requirement.

Comment: +1 as suggestion of getting data for the labels and link text of localised content in some file or excel sheet and compare , seconds my way of approaching the problem.

Comment: Cool, Glad that you solved it  :-)